# Android universal image downloader throws exception "unable to resolve host"

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I have downloaded sample code and jar file of universal image downloader from [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

But after running Sample app, it throws exception "unable to resolve host" for all images.

I checked permission in menifest file, which is as follows :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And my image URL is working in browser.

Then what can other causes of this problem?

Comment: The error basically means that the hostname of the URL cannot be translated to an IP address. How do you run the sample app? On a real phone? Does it have access to the network with the host?